# Eclipse выдает предупреждение Access restriction

Tags: java, eclipse, права, доступ, warning

Напротив этого кода:

```
com.sun.javafx.webkit.Accessor.getPageFor(web.getEngine()).setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Eclipse выдает предупреждение:

> Access restriction: The type 'WebPage' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar')

Comment: А какая версия Java ?

Comment: Попробуй на Java7

Comment: Java 8, на 7 не работает программа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

дело в том что некоторые пакеты из общедоступных библиотек защишены от постороннего доступа. Это можно изменить в настройках Eclipse.

Решение заключается в изменении ограничений доступа:

- Перейдите в свойства вашего Java-проекта,
       то есть выбрав «Свойства» из контекстного меню проекта в «Проводнике пакетов».
- Перейдите на «Путь Сборки Java», вкладку «Библиотеки».
- Расширить вход в библиотеку
- Выбрать

  - «Правила доступа»,
  - «Изменить ...» и
  - «Добавить ...» «Разрешение: Доступно» с соответствующим шаблоном правила. Например, `com/sun/javafx/**`.

Comment: Т.е. это не влияет работу программы, это проблема Eclipse?

Comment: я бы не сказал, что это проблема Eclipse, который лишь предупреждает об использовании защищенного кода. Если у вас есть ошибки то это куда сложнее, тем не менее если вы запускаете вашу программу с помощью Eclipse то ошибки доступа не должны появляться после того как вы добавите правила доступа.